# Can repeated hyperventilation change the setpoint for oxygen sensitivity?

Tags: breathing, health-risk

In recent years, breath-hold diving as a competitive sport has developed tremendously. I'm interested in generally understanding the consequences of training for maximum breath hold times on a person's general health and well-being. (I plan to ask several questions on this topic.)

For this question, I specifically wish to understand if it **is true that "repeated hyperventilation can change the point at which your body believes it needs more oxygen."**

The following statements were made in an answer to another [question](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/36588/32651) here. There was no further comment on it. I am turning this into a question.

> More anecdotally, I've heard that repeated hyperventilation can change the point at which your body believes it needs more oxygen, which can eventually lead to not getting sufficient oxygenation because you've effectively trained your brain into believing that famine is the new norm. However, I can't find any actual scientific proof of that online, so that could be a wives tale.

Comment: This...isn't really on topic for the site if you are asking about the health aspect of it. If you want to know about how to train for maximum breath holding, that could be on topic. Asking if it changes the set point would be more of a biology type question.

Comment: It is in the context of training for maximum breath holds. Furthermore, we have evidence the topic is applicable to fitness in general.